# How to Enable Auto Resolution for UTM VM

Tags: macos, ubuntu, utm, superuser

Currently setting up a Ubuntu VM using UTM on my Mac. However, I cannot figure out how to make the resolution of the VM dynamically scale to the window size.

Attempted to follow these docs, but they do not specify where to find the option to enable the setting. https://docs.getutm.app/guest-support/dynamic-resolution/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

right click on the ubuntu linux icon and select edit.Then go to the display settings and there you should be able to see the auto resolution settings.